# Python loop with int iterator

Tags: python, loops

I seem to recall there is a built-in way of doing this:

```
i = 0
for value in values:
    # ...Stuff
    i += 1
```

but in a neater syntax; something like

```
for value, i in fn(values):
    # ...Stuff
```

Is my memory correct; and if so, what is the way of doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for i, value in enumerate(values):
```